# Style bottom post Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

How to add class "bottom-post" to the post that is at the very bottom of my wordpress blogroll? I need to style it differently. (I can't use the static ID since the the post and the total number of posts are constantly changing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add classes to elements with jQuery:

```
$(".post:last-child").addClass("bottom-post");
```

and then style like so:

```
.bottom-post {
    /* Different styling */
}
```

A benefit of this method (compared to using pure css) is that this will apply the class to the element and allow styling even on browsers that don't support the `:last-child` css selector. I tested this on IE6-8 and it worked in all of them.

The following provides an explanation as to why the `:last-child` psuedo selector tends to be preferred over `:last` in this case:

http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS pseudo class `:last-child` to select the last post.

For Example:

> ```
> .post:last-child
> {
>     color: red;
> }
> ```

Link me to your blog and I'll be able to give a working example.